# Laravel 5.2 : set and get session with multiple variables

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I need to set an session with multiple variables and then get the session back in the next page.

here what I try

in controller

```
public function postInvoice(Request $request)
    {
        $name = $request->name;
        $email = $request->email;
        $phone = $request->phone;
        $zip = $request->zip;
        $country = $request->country;
        $street_address = $request->street_address;
        $city = $request->city;
        $state = $request->state;

        Session::flash('userInfo', [$name, $email, $phone, $zip, $country, $street_address, $city, $state]);
        return view('portal.cart.standardPayment');
    }
```

and then in my blade page when I try to get the session back
I try

```
{!! Session::get('userInfo', $name) !!}
```

but got

> Undefined variable: name

How can I get the session variables from the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing array of values, so try `Session::get('userInfo')[0]`. The `get` function second parameter is the default value

Comment: Nice idea so if I need to add something like `Session::get('userInfo')[name]` I need to change the `Session::flash` to be something like `Session::flash('userInfo', ['name'=>'$name']` yes??

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is late, but it may help someone.

If you want to store an array of data in session, the easiest way to do it is:

1. using session()->push() method

```php
session()->push('user.first_name', 'John');
```

2. using session()->put('array_name', [])

```php
session()->put('names', ['john', 'doe']);
```

[Laravel Sessions Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/session)

Comment: Aha it's not just late answer it's also different version of Laravel I was using Laravel 5.2 at that time anyway thanks dear I think it will help others who using newest Laravel version.

Comment: Its my pleasure.